# signal between father and son and fork in C

Tags: linux, signals, fork, wait, sleep

Hello everyone and thanks to take time to answer me .
I have a little problem :

the problem is :
 Do a programm with fork(). The son sleep 10sec, father sleep 1 sec and send a signal SIGUSR1 to his son and wait that son finish his programm.

I did that :`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void tononcle (int sig){
printf("signal %d recu\n",sig);

}

int main (){
int pid,status;
pid = fork();
if(pid){

printf("%s\n","Pere");
sleep(1);
kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
wait(&status);
exit(0);
}
else{

printf("%s\n","fils");
sleep(10);
signal(SIGUSR1,tononcle);

exit(0);

}
return 0;
}`
```

The problem is that my son doesn't sleep 10sec before the end of his programm.. 
Someone has a idea please?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void tononcle (int sig){
    printf("signal %d recu\n",sig);
}

int main (){
    int pid,status;
    pid = fork();

    switch(pid) {
        case -1:
            printf("Fork failed");
            break;
        case 0:
            signal(SIGUSR1,tononcle);
            printf("%s\n","fils");
            sleep(10);
            break;
        default:
            printf("%s\n","Pere");
            sleep(1);
            //kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
            waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
            exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When you send message with kill(), the son process wake up. You just need to comment the ligne where you send the signal.

Comment: Okay, but finally, the father doesn't a signal? ,
 To finish, the program lasts 11 sec .. is it right?

Comment: Yes it is. because the father sleep 1 sec and its son also sleep 10 sec, total give 11 sec

Comment: You can send signal between the two processes, but you have just to specify a context

Comment: If you want my code to send the message you must uncomment the line that contains kill (). With this the child process will no longer sleep for 10s